# Static Methods in Android

Tags: java, android

Im try to create a drawing app.  In my main activity I have an XML file which contains a drawing viewview

```
<app.color.DrawingView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:layout_above="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

This is based on my drawing view class:

```
package app.color;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Get the coordinates of the touch event.
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Set a new starting point
                path.moveTo(eventX,      return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Connect the points
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void setColor(String newColor){
        invalidate();
        int paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        paint.setColor(paintColor);
    }
}
```

Then in another activity on a button click I have a method which which I want to be able to call the setColor method in drawingView to change the color.  However it wont let me do this because a "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

```
public void toBlack(View view)
{
    DrawingView.setColor("#00000");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Colors.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a instance of DrawingView.

thats like ,

```
DrawingView drawingview = new DrawingView();
drawingview.setColor("#00000");
```

`setColor` is an instance method, meaning you need an instance of the `DrawingView` class in order to call it. You're attempting to call it on the `DrawingView` type itself.

just make your code to

```
DrawingView dv = new DrawingView(); 
dv.setColor("#00000");
Intent intent = new Intent(Colors.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

for example you already have

```
public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
}
```

you can also have another empty constructor 
like

```
public DrawingView() { }
```

Comment: Is there already an instance created since I can see the drawing view when I run my app without creating an instance?

Comment: Also what class to I create the instance in my main class or the class I call setColor from?

Comment: 1) no instance not already created , you see drawing because of hardcode in xml , not because you java code, 2) In the class you call setColor

Comment: Thanks.  What do I pass in as the parameters of DrawingView() ?

Comment: nothing , that actually depends on constructor defined on class(DrawingView) , you can always have empy constructor defined.

Comment: @Mike If you declared your `DrawingView` in XML, there *is* an instance of it.  You can get a reference to it by calling `findViewById(int)`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Thank You!  That's what I was trying to figure out I just didn't know how to word it.  However, when I put the line: DrawingView dv = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing); into my code I get no errors in android studio by my app crashes when I try to run it...?

Comment: stack trace is errors shown in logcat below , more specific , use try catch exception handling , in catch case "e.getmessage" or simmilar to it

Answer (score 0):

setColor is not a static method.  You need to call it on an instance of DrawingView.